# JavaScript simple unit conversion with unit selection

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a unit converter with a dropdown selection of units but I'm struggling to find a simple example. Could anyone share their knowledge, an example or direct me to a tutorial?
I'm new to JavaScript and have looked at the source code of several conversion websites and understand I need to use an array but I can't seem to following how the code looks at the user input unit then converts it using the factors in the array to the selected output unit. I would like a step by step guide of some type.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what are you looking to convert?

Comment: You'll need to post some code that you are having trouble understanding and then ask specific questions about what you don't understand.

Comment: I would like a very simple example where a user has a number input with a selection of units, then another number input which is disabled and will display the result of the function, this input has a unit selector also and finally a button which onclick will call the function.
Something simple like mm,cm,m,km,T,lb etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<select id="inputOptions" onchange="change()">
<option >meter</option>
<option>cm</option>
</select>

<input type="text" readonly id="result" id="result"/>
<select id="resultOptions" onchange="change()">
<option>meter</option>
<option>cm</option>
</select>

<script>
function change()
{
var inputValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
var inputUnit = document.getElementById("inputOptions").value;
var outputUnit = document.getElementById("resultOptions").value;

var convertedResult;

if(inputUnit === 'meter'){
        if(outputUnit ==='meter'){
    convertedResult = inputValue;
    }
    else
    {
        convertedResult = inputValue * 100;
    }
}
else
{
            if(outputUnit ==='meter'){
    convertedResult = inputValue / 100;
    }
    else
    {
        convertedResult = inputValue;
    }
}

document.getElementById("result").value = convertedResult;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  $("#cur_value").remove();
  $(document.body).append("<span id='cur_value'>" + $(this).val() + "</span>");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="currency">
    <option value=".9">USD</option>
    <option value=".008">YEN</option>
  </select>
</form>

<span> conversion rate to EURO: </span>
```